# entity reference with multiple values?

Tags: entities

I've added a new field to a content type, using the Entity Reference module.

The new field is to allow entry of up to 4 related articles (curated content - chosen by the admin) per article.
I've set the field to allow up to 4 values - but using the 'Autocomplete (tags style)' widget it doesn't seem possible to enter more than one option.

Any suggestions/solutions?

Comment: I think just plain old "Autocomplete" (no "tags style") is what you want, but if you can post some screenshots of your field configuration, that might be helpful as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To select multiple items with "Autocomplete (tags style)", you must enter a comma-separated list in the text box. Otherwise, if you want to enter the values in separate text boxes, use the plain "Autocomplete" widget type.